# Path Doesn't Exist

Tags: java, file, exception, path

I decided to test the file creating possibilities Java has to offer:

I tried to make a program that creates a file on a systems desktop.

To get the location, I did the following:

```
String targetLoc = System.getProperties("user.home") + "/Desktop"; //Returns /Users/targetUser/Desktop
```

And to then create the file:

```
File file = new File(targetLoc + "/testfile.txt"); //I'm aware of the slash before the name :)

try{

file.createNewFile();

}catch(Exception exception){

exception.printStackTrace();

}
```

And even though I don't see any errors above, I get the `InvalidPathException`.

Why would I get that error?

StackTrace On Request:

```
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:883)
at com.Code0.FileCreater.Main.MainFF.main(MainFF.java:41)
```

Answer:

It was a simple screw-up where I assigned the wrong value to the home String variable.

Comment: you got the rights to create that file in that location?

Comment: How are you being able to call System.getProperties("user.home")?

Comment: I'm only running this on my computer, if you meant that @thumbmunkeys

Comment: Can you please post the full stack trace?

Comment: Is this really all of the code?  Outside of the try-catch, you only have four lines of code - 1) getting properties, 2) instantiating a `File` instance, 3) calling `createNewFile`, and 4) printing the stacktrace.  None of those methods will throw an `InvalidPathException` (according to the javadoc).  Additionally, `System.getProperties` does not accept arguments.

Comment: Also please show file.getPath().

Comment: @matt Yes, that was a typo. Fixed it, but didn't change the outcome.

Comment: What is line 41 of `MainFF.java`?

Comment: Question was answered. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple screw-up where I assigned the wrong value to the home String variable.

Thank all of you very much for your support.

Regards,

Code0